# Pandas DataFrame grouping by Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a use case where:

Data is of the form: Col1, Col2, Col3 and Timestamp.

Now, I just want to get the counts of the rows vs Timestamp Bins.

i.e. for every half hour bucket (even the ones which have no correponding rows), I need the counts of how many rows are there.

Timestamps are spread over a one year period, so I can't divide it into 24 buckets.

I have to bin them at 30 minutes interval.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### `groupby` via `pd.Grouper`

```
# optionally, if needed
# df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')  
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='30min')).count()
```

---

### `resample`

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('30min').count()
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED thanks a lot! it works! what does errors=coerce do? And one more question: resample does it sample all the rows?

Comment: @davidnadal it will convert invalid datetime strings to NaT (instead of throwing parser errors). Resample will sample all rows.